# Projects list, click to display tasks (Gantt)

Tags: task-list

We´r running SharePoint 2010 Server and i´m about to try out the projects part in SharePoint.

I would like a list of projects, behind each project there is a list of tasks (Project Tasks List (Gantt)), when the user click a project the task list is displayed.

The problem is that i dont know where to begin...

Thanks!

Best regards

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require some customization. There are two "easy" routes you can take, depending on your comfort level

If you know jQuery, you could throw a script on the page to find the links to the project details, and change them to go to the tasks list, filtered by the project.

If you don't, you can use SharePoint designer and convert the web part to a "XSLT Data View" (search for that you'll find a plethora of articles on how). Once converted you can modify the hyperlink to go where you want.

If you're using a single tasks list for all of your projects, you can hyperlink to a tasks list and filter on it by doing something like

`http://site/lists/tasks/allitems.aspx?FilterField1=Project&FilterValue1=ProjectName`

where allitems.aspx is the view you want to use. You can play with this by going to your view, then filter the view using the column header. Then note the values in the browser's address bar.

HTH

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response!

Okay, i could use either jQuery or filter the tasks based on values.

Comment: using jquery would be more "lightweight" if you're already including the jquery references. Just plop a content web part on the page and script it out.

Comment: Oupps, my comment timed out... To slow... 

Here comes the previous answer plus this one :)


No problem with either solution. 
Just dont want to build some customized solution before making sure there is no way of using SharePoint standard. 

Im going to persist all project tasks in one single list. Seems more efficient to just filter out the ones needed. 

And i can use the standard Project Task List when scripting? 
Want to use the Gantt presentation. 

Thanks a lot for your input! 

//R

Comment: Yes sir, you can use the gantt view and perform the same FilterField/Value query string as noted above.

Comment: I just thought of another possible solution, no customization, is to use grouping in a view. I don't think it works in gantt, but you could group your tasks, which would give you the list of projects, then click to expand that project's tasks.

Comment: Splendid, then thats my solution!

Comment: Going for the jQuery solution.

Comment: Excellent, glad i could help. Make to post a new question if you need help with the jQuery piece.